# Splitting a dictionary's multiple values from one key

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary

I have the dictionary:

```
dict1 = {'A': {'val1': '5', 'val2': '1'},
  'B': {'val1': '10', 'val2': '10'},
  'C': {'val1': '15', 'val3': '100'}
```

Here, I have one key, with two values. I can obtain the key by using:

```
letters = dict1.keys()
```

which returns:

```
 ['A', 'B', 'C']
```

I am use to working with arrays and being able to "slice" them. How can I break this dictionary in a similar way as the key for the values?

```
 val1_and_val2 = dict1.values()
```

returns:

```
 [{'val1': '5', 'val2': '1'},
{'val1': '10', 'val2': '10'},
{'val1': '15', 'val2': '100'}]
```

How can I get:

```
 number1 = [5, 10, 15]
 number2 = [1, 10, 100]
```

Comment: `[v['val1'] for v in dict1.values()]`

Comment: Ah! Thank you so much! Can you put this as an answer instead of a comment so you may get credit and I can have this question closed?

Comment: Oh didn't see the comment above, I guess they got there while I was answering. Anyway, feel free to wait for them, I don't really care. :)

Comment: What do you mean "one key with two values"? A dictionary can only have on value per key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly then:

```
number1 = [val["val1"] for val in dict1.values()]
```

If you prefer, this will accomplish the same thing with lambdas.

```
number1 = map(lambda value: value["val1"], dict1.values())
```

Note how you really need to take the dict1[key]["val1"] to get an individual value.

Comment: Got it. Can I also use this if I want the dictionary to contain key, val1 and another dictionary to contain key, val2 instead of the two isolated values from the key? Just curious as I am playing around with this code. As for lamda, I have not heard of it or looked into it yet, so I will stay away from that until I learn more about it!

Comment: I'm sorry can you clarify what you mean by "Can I also use this if I want the dictionary to contain key, val1 and another dictionary to contain key, val2 instead of the two isolated values from the key?" The expected output you provided previously of [5, 10, 15] was perfect.

Comment: Lambdas are cool, if you've written Javascript they will be familiar, otherwise, your right to not go off on random tangents too often, I get it! :)

Comment: Yes, this answer is what I am looking for. What I mean in the comments is if I can manipulate your answer to get this for val1 or val2 :{'A': 5,
 'B': 10,
 'C': 15}

Comment: Oh thats fun give me a minute.

Comment: `{key:value["val1"] for (key,value) in dict1.iteritems()}`